# C# read multiple parameters from command line

Tags: c#

If I want to execute like this, common in other languages: program.exe -u user -p password

How can I code this in C# main()?

Comment: Use an existing command line parser

Answer (score 5):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
}
```

and `args` array will contain list of arguments.

Comment: For completeness, the full method signature is `static void Main(string[] args)`

Answer (score 1):

How to solve this problem using `NDesk.Options`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Loading via the command line; parse command line args
    string username = string.Empty;
    string password = string.Empty;

    OptionSet CmdParser = new OptionSet
    {
        { "u|username=", "Username",  u => username = u },
        { "p|password=", "Password",  p => password = p }
    };

    try
    {
        // Loading via the command line; parse command line arguments
        List<string> unknownArgs = CmdParser.Parse(args);
        if (unknownArgs.Count > 1)
        {
            Console.Write("Unrecognised argument in: '{0}'", string.Join(" ", unknownArgs));
        }
    }
    catch (OptionException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: how about another one is: int days? it's int not string.

Comment: @JirongHu not sure what you mean. You want to capture an integer argument?

Answer (score 1):

For a more functional oriented approach, you can install the latest version of the command line parser

```
Install-Package CommandLineParser -pre
```

define an option class

```
 class Options
 {
     [Option('u', "user", Required = true, HelpText = "username")]
     public string UserName { get; set; }

     [Option('p', "password", Required = true, HelpText = "password")]
     public string Password { get; set; }

     [Value(0)]
     public IEnumerable<string> StringSequence { get; set; }
 }
```

and parse the command line

```
class Program
{
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        var parser = new Parser(settings =>
        {
            settings.CaseSensitive = false;
            settings.HelpWriter = Console.Error;
            settings.IgnoreUnknownArguments = false;
        });

        var result = parser.ParseArguments<Options>(args);
        var exitCode = result
.MapResult(
  options =>
  {

      if (options.StringSequence.Count() > 0)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("unbound params: " +
          String.Join(",", options.StringSequence)
          );
          return 1;
      }
      Console.WriteLine("Hi " + options.UserName + ", your password is");
      Console.WriteLine(options.Password);
      return 0;
  },
  errors =>
  {
      Console.WriteLine(
          String.Join(",",
          errors.Select(x => x.ToString())
          )
          );
      return 1;
  });
        return exitCode;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var user = args[1];
    var password = args[3];
}
```

That's an anemic implementation and like others that have already replied I'd recommend you use a nuget package to do this work.

Here are 2 that I've used before(I didn't test these implementations but they should get you 80% of the way there):

http://www.ndesk.org/Options

```
static void Main(string[] args)
       {
              string user = string.Empty;
              string password = string.Empty;
              int verbose = 0;
              var p = new OptionSet () {
               { "u|user",      v => user = v },
               { "p|password",  v => password = v },
              };
              List<string> extra = p.Parse (args);
              Console.WriteLine($"user:{user}");
       }
```

https://commandline.codeplex.com/

```
// Define a class to receive parsed values
class Options {
  [Option('u', "user", Required=true, HelpText="username")]
  public string UserName { get; set; }     

  [Option('p', "password", Required=true, HelpText="password")]
  public string Password { get; set; }

  [ParserState]
  public IParserState LastParserState { get; set; }

  [HelpOption]
  public string GetUsage() {
    return HelpText.AutoBuild(this,
      (HelpText current) => HelpText.DefaultParsingErrorsHandler(this, current));
  }
}

// Consume them
static void Main(string[] args) {
  var options = new Options();
  if (CommandLine.Parser.Default.ParseArguments(args, options)) 
  {
         // Values are available here
        Console.WriteLine($"UserName:{options.UserName}");
  }
}
```